# The sum of my column doesn't appear to give me the correct result in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The sum of my column doesn't appear to give me the correct result which should be: 2183277331

```
> str(begge)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ totex_loen      : num  6.69e+08 1.51e+09
 $ normgrid_gis    : num  4563 5642
 $ aftagenumre_2019: int  394195 1023735
 $ leveret         : num  3.90e+09 8.21e+09

> dput(begge)
structure(list(totex_loen = c(669453353.59237, 1513823976.81722
), normgrid_gis = c(4562.8969713252, 5642.496152377), aftagenumre_2019 = c(394195L, 
1023735L), leveret = c(3897556393, 8206787067)), row.names = c(1L, 
28L), class = "data.frame")

> sum(begge$totex_loen)
[1] 2183277330
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0PCG.png)

[sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k54lZ.png)

Comment: Please share your data.frame using ``dput(begge)`` rather than as an image. Thank you.

Comment: alright, i see now that the value that is being sum corresponds with the one show by dput. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a floating point issue. Using round should do the trick.

```
begge <- structure(list(totex_loen = c(669453353.59237, 1513823976.81722
), normgrid_gis = c(4562.8969713252, 5642.496152377), aftagenumre_2019 = c(394195L, 
                                                                           1023735L), leveret = c(3897556393, 8206787067)), row.names = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                          28L), class = "data.frame")
begge
#>    totex_loen normgrid_gis aftagenumre_2019    leveret
#> 1   669453354     4562.897           394195 3897556393
#> 28 1513823977     5642.496          1023735 8206787067

sum(round(begge$totex_loen))
#> [1] 2183277331
Created on 2021-06-25 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```